# bad interpreter: Permission denied error when running Ruby from Git Bash

Tags: windows, git, rubygems

```
$ gem install jekyll
sh.exe": /c/ruby/bin/gem: C:/ruby/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

when i am running gem install jeklly in git Bash,who can tell me how to change the permission.

the OS is windows xp.

thanks a lot!

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - VERSION: 0.9.4 (0.9.4)
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM PATH:
     - c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the ownership of the ruby folder to the current user..

Or try opening the cmd as an administrator by right-cliking `cmd -> run as administrator`

Comment: the problem missing when i update the version of ruby to 1.9.2

Comment: Not sure where is the problem then

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Windows 7 environment.  I had to change the PATH environment variable by including all of the paths associated with RoR in quotes.  Specifically the following path: 
...;c:/Program Files (x86)... 
was monified to 
...;"C:/Program Files (x86)...";

This fixed the issue for me.  Hope it helps.